# Is it possibile suppose next in a series

Tags: probability, algorithms, neural-networks

just for clarify i'm not a math :D and i'm a little bit ignorant in some topics of math :D.
I would like to understand one thing.
Assume that we have thousands of string in example 
[aaa]ppppp
[bbb]ppppp
[aaa]zzzz 
and so on so forth.
I group all the strings by first 3 letters in square bracket ad assign to them a number like 1 and 0 in a static way ossia aaa=1 and bbb=0 always.

After read the integral file I have the following result:

Number 0 [aaa] = 25%
Number 1 [bbb] = 75%

I left 10.000 record to read in order to try to understand if there's a way to "predict" in any manner the next result in the file in example it will be 0 or 1.

Is there any way to achieve this or not(Neuralnet or any other stuff)? I know that there' a probability that the event occurs or not. I would like to understand if there's a way to calculate the next element in any way with an accurate low error range.

Here a small sample

ID - VALUE -STRING

1 - 0 - [AAA]ABCDF

2 - 0 - [AAA]ABCDF

3 - 1 - [BBB]ABCDF

4 - 0 - [BBB]ABCDF

5 - 0 - [AAA]ABCDF

6 - 1 - [BBB]ABCDF

7 - 0 - [AAA]ABCDF

8 - 0 - [AAA]ABCDF

9 - 1 - [BBB]ABCDF

10 - 0 - [AAA]ABCDF

11 - 0 - [AAA]ABCDF

12 - 0 - [AAA]ABCDF

13 - 0 - [AAA]ABCDF

14 - 1 - [BBB]ABCDF

15 - 0 - [AAA]ABCDF

16 - 0 - [AAA]KDKJJD

Where ID is a field which is not related to this question. Value should be only 0-1 and which is derived from square bracket content [aaa(0) | bbb(1)]

Comment: **How** do you assign the numbers $0$ and $1$ to the strings? Randomly? Please be *much clearer* in your question otherwise people might start downvoting it. *(it's not because you don't know maths you get downvoted, it's because you don't show effort / your question is unclear)*

Comment: Sorry TobyMak, no it is static in example aaa=1 and bbb=0. Fixed in order to understand the percentage of each within the dataset.

Comment: Update the question Toby, thanks

Comment: If they are static, do you know what combinations are '0's and what combinations are '1's? Otherwise, can you show us some of the data (so that I can make some conclusions for it).

Comment: i'll do it few minutes :) thanks toby

Comment: Update the question @TobyMak with the info required. I hope it is much clear now. About combination we know that each string start with different "pattern" in example "aaa" or "bbb" and each one is not directly related to previous one in no way. Is there a way to predict via neural network or any formula the next element after the 16th?